# Django Model function behavior changes based on how many tests being run

Tags: django

I have a need for a uniqueID within my Django code. I wrote a simple model like this

```
class UniqueIDGenerator(models.Model):
    nextID = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)

    @classmethod
    def getNextID(self):
        if(self.objects.filter(id=1).exists()):
            idValue = self.objects.get(id=1).nextID
            idValue += 1
            self.objects.filter(id=1).update(nextID=idValue)
            return idValue

        tempObj = self(nextID=1)
        tempObj.save()
        return tempObj.nextID
```

Then I wrote a unit test like this:

```
class ModelWorking(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        return None

    def test_IDGenerator(self):
        returnValue = UniqueIDGenerator.getNextID()
        self.assertEqual(returnValue, 1)
        returnValue = UniqueIDGenerator.getNextID()
        self.assertEqual(returnValue, 2)
        return None
```

When I run this test by itself, it runs fine. No issues.

When I run this test as a suite, which includes a bunch of other unit tests as well (*which include calls to getNextID() as well*), this test fails. The getNextID() always returns 1. Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Django runs each test in a transaction to provide isolation. Doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/).

Since my other tests make a call to getNextID(), the first row gets deleted after the first test that makes such a call is complete. Subsequent tests never find (id=1), due to which all subsequent calls return the value 1.

Even though I don't think I would face that situation in production, I went I ahead and changed my code to use .first() instead of (id=1). Like this

```
    def getNextID(self):
        firstRow = self.objects.first()
        if(firstRow):
```

That way I believe it would better handle any future scenario when the database table might be emptied.